# Creating GDI+ 2D Grid but I have slow performance

Tags: vb.net

I have created Bitmap `map` with size `(mapWidth, mapHeight)`. I filled it with squares which size is : `cellSize`.

Then previously created bitmap `map` which is filled with squares.

```
map = New Bitmap(mapWidth, mapHeight)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(map)
Dim pen As Pen = New Pen(Color.FromArgb(50, 255, 255, 255))
```

[This is the grid inside picturebox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1nM9.png)

Now that I stored my grid inside bitmap Everything is ok. But what I want to achieve is if I press arrow keys, to move across that grid just like some 2d top down game.

So, if I want to move my View across the Grid I have to change map position by completely redrawing it with new starting x,y coordinates.

If I want to move UP, When I press KEY_UP I lower the y coordinate by `moveSpeed` and then redraw image at that y position. But if I want to redraw image with size 5000x5000 10 times in 2 seconds, it is really bad for perfomance.

What I did is, I tried to draw only region of `map` with size of my viewx, viewy. So instead of drawing whole map I only draw region of map(800, 640) which is my form size. That is only thing I did to fix perfomance.

But still, if I hold the KEY_UP and 800, 640 pixels are being redrawn as long as I hold the KEY_UP and it Still takes 50+% of my processor.

My code:

```
Private Sub draw_map()
    Dim xx As Integer = 0
    Dim yy As Integer = 0

    x1 = 200
    x2 = 200
    y1 = 200
    y2 = 200

    map = New Bitmap(mapWidth, mapHeight)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(map)
    Dim pen As Pen = New Pen(Color.FromArgb(50, 255, 255, 255))
    cellSize = 32
    Do Until viewx Mod cellSize = 0
        cellSize -= 1
    Loop


    For i As Integer = 0 To mapWidth / cellSize Step 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To mapHeight / cellSize Step 1
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, xx, yy, cellSize, cellSize)
            xx += cellSize
        Next
        yy += cellSize
        xx = 0
    Next



    'mapScreen.Image = map
    g.Dispose()
    pen.Dispose()

    mapPosition = New Bitmap(viewx, viewy)

    LoadPartOfMap((map.Width / 2) - (viewx / 2), (map.Height / 2) - (viewy / 2), viewx, viewy)

End Sub

Private Sub LoadPartOfMap(ByVal xx As Integer, ByVal yy As Integer, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer)

    curX = xx
    curY = yy
    Dim ds_rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(xx, yy, width, height)

    'mapPosition = New Bitmap(width, height)
    grNew = Graphics.FromImage(mapPosition)
    grNew.Clear(Color.Black)
    grNew.DrawImage(map, 0, 0, ds_rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

    mapScreen.Image = mapPosition
    grNew.Dispose()


End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Up
            LoadPartOfMap(curX, curY - 5, viewx, viewy)
        Case Keys.Left
        Case Keys.Right
        Case Keys.Down

    End Select
End Sub
```

Is there any way to improve the perfomance?

I would really like to move only my camera and not the image. But I dont think that is possible.

Comment: If you are drawing your entire map, even beyond the bounds of the screen, that is wasting a ton of CPU time for drawing.  You need to find a way to only paint what fits on screen (or *just* slightly off screen), instead of the entire map.  Also, try not to recreate the bitmap every time, you can keep it around and reuse it by clearing it before drawing.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for fast reply. I wrote down that I already did that. I only Draw 800, 640 pixels out of 5000, 5000.

Comment: You will also want to call `Dispose` on any temporary Bitmaps you use when you are done with them.

Comment: You can also optimize your grid drawing code by drawing just horizontal and vertical lines across the entire screen, instead of individual rectangles.

Comment: To fix your scrolling performance, you can use the concept of "dirty rectangles".  When the map scrolls, don't recompute the drawing, just shift the existing image over a few pixels and then repaint *just* the blank area.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your reply about "dirty rectangles", do you think that I draw the rectangles whenever I move ? If that is the case, then answer is NO. On from_load I draw_map (whole grid with squares) then I only display part of It (800, 640) that is my form size. As I move, I clear whole image, then redraw another part of map with different start of rectangle... and so on

Comment: I think you would get better performance if you draw and redraw the lines instead. It would require more code and math, but less actual drawing.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks for your reply. Drawing lines or squares isn't the problem. Because that is only the picture which is being draw at the beginning and then I only CROP a bit of that image to fit my picturebox size. And then as I press KEY UP I want to just crop another bits of image and clearing image that is out of bounds.

Comment: But that's the thing. If I'm not mistaken it takes longer time to draw an image than to just draw lines.

Comment: It has to be an image, because I am going to draw something on it, and then when I move the grid, it needs to stay on image.